# php div content swap - how to include in echo command

Tags: php, mysql

syntax:

```
   echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/mdesign.css' />"; 
echo "<div id=swap>";
echo "<div id=one>One</div>";
echo "<div id=two>Two</div>";
echo "<div id=three>Three</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<a href=#one>One</a>";
echo "<a href=#two>Two</a>";
echo "<a href=#three>Three</a>";
```

how i can change above souce code:

http://www.visibilityinherit.com/code/css-content-swap-demo1.php  - original code

Comment: could you clear you question more ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just some suggestions:
Firstly, it's good practise to enclose the values of tag attributes in quotes. For instance:

```
echo "<div id=swap>";   becomes
echo "<div id='swap'>";
```

Comment: No JS, it's just CSS and HTML

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this css also

```
<style type="text/css">
#swap {
float:right;
height:30em;
width:300px;
overflow:hidden;
border:1px solid;
}
#one, #two, #three {
height:30em;
}
#one{background:red;}
#two{background:blue;}
#three{background:green;}
</style>
```

Comment: @bajis Have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably link to your css file has the wrong path

Answer (score 0):

That example is reliant on a specific CSS layout, using anchor tags to switch the content. It's not going to be practical in a production environment. Essentially it's a box with the scrollbars hidden. When clicking the anchor links, it moves the selected content into view, appearing as if it's switched the content. You can test this by turning off 'overflow:hidden' on the #swap div.

Your question suggests that this is a PHP issue, but it's entirely unrelated. The example is an HTML/CSS implementation, and so long as you're outputting the correct HTML from PHP, it's going to be a CSS bug.

As I mentioned before, this sort of 'content switching' isn't going to be of much use for anything other than a CSS experiment. I'd take a look at [jQuery's html() method](http://api.jquery.com/html/).